# Как с помощью mockito подменить вызов метода который ни чего не возвращает

Tags: spring, mockito

Пытаюсь с помощью mockito подменить вызов метода, который возвращает void. Код сильно упростил, чтобы уменьшить его. Имеется сервис

```
@Service
public class CalService {
  public void createTable(DataAtributes attr) {
    ...
  }
  public Integer addAttr(DataAtributes attr) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

и еще один класс, который вызывает метод из CalService

```
@Component
public class GetCalcService {
  @Autowired
  private CalService calService ;
  DataAtributes dataAtributes;
  public Integer setCalc() {
    dataAtributes = new DataAtributes(1,"test");
    Integer val = calService.addAttr(dataAtributes);
    calService.createTable(dataAtributes);
    return val;
  }
}
```

и сам класс тестирования

```
@SpringBootTest
public class CaclServisTest {
  @Mock
  CalService calcService;
  @InjectMocks
  GetCalcService getCalcService ;
  @Test
  void add() {
    DataAtributes dataAtributes = new DataAtributes(1,"test");
    when(calcService.addAttr(dataAtributes)).thenReturn(57);
    Integer calc = getCalcService.setCalc();
    log.info("calc = " + calc);      
  }
}
```

С методом addAttr все получилось.
А вот как мне подменить вызов метода calService.createTable(dataAtributes) или сделать, так чтобы он не вызывался в тесте?
Просто подменить метод setCalc нельзя, на самом деле в нем идет вызов нескольких методов и только один из них (createTable) необходимо подменить или проигногрировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Mockito` есть несколько методов для работы с методами, которые возвращают `void`. В этом случае используйте `Mockito.doNothing` так:

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(calServiceMock).createTable(dataAttributes);
```